# Replace some string part with another Django

Tags: python, django, replace

Hi. In my template file, I'm getting the value of field like

```
{{product.description}}
```

It gives me the `br` tags with in the description. How can I replace them? Actually I have migrated the products from the magento to django.

Comment: Do you mean that it includes `<br>` in the HTML output, or in what you see (thus the HTML would be `&lt;br&gt;`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the django built in template tag 'safe':

```
{{product.description|safe}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [StripTag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags) Filter

```
{{ value|striptags }}
```